# Load SQL and SharePoint in PowerShell script

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, sql-server

I need to create one PowerShell in which i am using SQL and SharePoint both. In my development environment it works fine because there is single server for Content DB server and WFE server. But in production environment i have different server for Content Database and WFE.

If i run my PowerShell in WFE server then i am not getting reference of SQL and if I run my PowerShell in Content DB server then i am not getting SharePoint.

How i can get both (SQL and SharePoint) reference in PowerShell in WFE?

I have tried to load SQL dll manually using following code but still i am not getting assembly reference

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom('.\dll\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll') | out-null
```

Comment: How about using Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell ?

Comment: For that i need to run my powershell in Content DB server. Same problem i am getting. All sharepoint dll are missing in Content DB server.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood.. :) In that case I think Powershell Remoting is your best option. Try this article for a start: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/opal/2010/03/07/sharepoint-2010-with-windows-powershell-remoting-step-by-step/

Comment: There is so much limitations in powershell remoting. i have tried with no success :(